# Wordpress admin bar and template div

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, admin

So I have created a wordpress template, and when i log in into wordpress there is a admin bar over main menu. This div wraps the other div's of the website. 
My question is:
How can i set div margin-top: i.e. 50 pixels only when there is admin bar, ergo there is a user logged in?

EDIT:

So, this is my code of functions.php and it still doesnt work.

```
<?php
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
    return '...<br /><br /><a href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">Pročitaj još</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');

?>
<?php

if(is_admin_bar_showing() && !is_admin()) {
    function link_to_stylesheet() {
        ?>
            <style type="text/css">#wrapper{margin-top:150px;}</style>
        <?php
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'link_to_stylesheet');
}

?>
```

EDIT2:

I tried this too... It doesn't work.

```
<?php

if(is_admin_bar_showing() && !is_admin()) {
    function link_to_stylesheet() {
        ?>
        <style type="text/css">body{margin-top:150px;}</style>
        <?php
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'link_to_stylesheet');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To apply `top:50px` in admin bar when on front end, you may try this (put this in `functions.php`)

```
if(is_admin_bar_showing() && !is_admin()) {
    function link_to_stylesheet() {
        ?>
            <style type="text/css">#wpadminbar {top:50px;}</style>
        <?php
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'link_to_stylesheet');
}
```

To remove admin bar completely, you may try this (put this in `functions.php`)

```
add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
```

To remove admin bar from front end only for non-admin user (put this in `functions.php`)

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');
function remove_admin_bar() {
    if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin()) {
        show_admin_bar(false);
    }
}
```

You can setup from your back end (only for yourself) from `Users -> Your Profile` menu by removing check from

```
Show Toolbar when viewing site check box
```

Comment: I tried the first code because thats what i want... and it doesn't work. My div is called wrapper, so instead #wpadmin bar i put #wrapper  and margin-top:50px; but still not working...

Comment: <?php
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
 return '...<br /><br /><a href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">Pročitaj još</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');

?>
<?php

if(is_admin_bar_showing() && !is_admin()) {
    function link_to_stylesheet() {
        ?>
            <style type="text/css">#wrapper{margin-top:150px;}</style>
        <?php
    }
    add_action('wp_head', 'link_to_stylesheet');
}

?>

Comment: This will add `top:50px` to `adminbar` only when viewing `front end` as a logged in user.

Comment: It's `top:50px;`, not margin.

Comment: You should check for errors, this is working code, tested in my `WordPress version-3.7`. BTW, again, can you tell me what do you want ?

Comment: I want to achieve when a user is logged in, the whole page goes 50px down from top of the browser screen so there is a place for wordpress navigation bar.

Comment: The `admin bar` is absolutely positioned. it'll stay on `top`, if you change the position to `relative` it'll go to bottom, so you have to do something else, maybe `JavaScript` to re-position the `bar` on page load but not sure if there are other ways.

Comment: But, you may see the `margin-top:10px` of your `body` tag, so it'll left some space at the top in `<style type="text/css">body{margin-top:10px;}</style>` instead of setting the `top` property of `adminbar`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
<style  type="text/css" media="screen">
body{margin-top:28px !important;}
</style>
<?php } ?>
```

To the functions.php

Answer (score 0):

Whenever anybody is logged in and has a WPadminbar on the front-end

add this to your **functions.php**:

```
function adminbar_theme_setup() {
  add_theme_support( 'admin-bar', array( 'callback' => 'custom_admin_bar_css') );
}
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'adminbar_theme_setup' );

function custom_admin_bar_css() { ?>
<style>body{margin-top:28px !important;}</style>
<?php
}
```